# Trigger Key Not Working in Yasnippet emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, code-snippets, yasnippet

Yasnippet seems to be working but the trigger key is not.  I can load snippets, look at snippet tables and M-x yas/expand.  However, after typing a trigger key (i.e time) I'd like to expand the snippet with the TAB key which isn't working.  I checked the yasnippet.el file and found that the yas-trigger-key is set to .  I tried changing it and still couldn't get it working.  Anyone have an idea about what's going on?  I'm trying to get this working first in LaTeX mode.  Yasnippet tells me I should also try C-c C-s but that just seems to insert "\end."

I downloaded Yasnippet via the el-get packager manager.  I'm using OSX and emacs 23.4.1

Comment: Could you try M-x yas-expand RET (after your i.e. time)?

Comment: Yup, that works fine...it just doesn't like tab

Comment: Can you hit C-h k and then hit TAB? See what TAB is currently bound to (maybe it's not even TAB)?

Comment: "TAB runs the command indent-for-tab-command, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `indent.el'...." it's now bound correctly.  I tried to change it but it didn't work...

Comment: Well, TAB is supposed to run yas-expand, and if there is nothing to expand, then it should do whatever the user has assigned to TAB. That is a matter of correctly installing yas though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's *not*  bound correctly. Weird.  I can write "time", push tab, and nothing happens (I have yas-minor-mode enabled).  I can then do M-x yas-expand and it gets expanded...

Comment: So can you use "C-h k TAB" ? press those keys? See what it is bound and copy it here.

Comment: TAB runs the command forward-button, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function in `button.el'.

It is bound to TAB.

(forward-button N &optional WRAP DISPLAY-MESSAGE)

Move to the Nth next button, or Nth previous button if N is negative.
If N is 0, move to the start of any button at point.
If WRAP is non-nil, moving past either end of the buffer continues from the
other end.
If DISPLAY-MESSAGE is non-nil, the button's help-echo string is displayed.
Any button with a non-nil `skip' property is skipped over.
Returns the button found.

Comment: 'TAB (translated from <tab>) runs the command yas-expand, which is an
alias for `yas-expand-from-trigger-key' in `yasnippet.el'.

It is bound to TAB, <menu-bar> <YASnippet> <Expand trigger>.

(yas-expand &optional FIELD)

Expand a snippet before point. If no snippet
expansion is possible, call command....'

Comment: In other words, it isn't bound correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```elisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

Did you put the aforementioned in your .emacs?

Maybe try reinstalling from [this recent link](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet)

Comment: I finally got it working by using hippie-expand.  Thanks for taking the time to try and help. I found the following very helpful: https://gist.github.com/215930 .  That's what I'm currently using and it seems to work...we'll see how it fares in the long run.  Thanks again!